# Boolean Condition Group By, Window Functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, jquery-selectors, window-functions

I am trying to add a new column based on a condition in a group.
Could we do something like 
`BOOL() OVER (PARTITION BY id 'D' in val)`
That is something like GROUP BY `id` and check if the value 'D" val column

Input:

```
-------------
| id  | val |
------------|
|  1  |  A  |
|  1  |  B  |
|  1  |  D  |
|  2  |  B  |
|  2  |  C  |
|  2  |  A  |
```

Output

```
-------------------
| id  | val | res |
------------|-----|
|  1  |  A  |  1  |
|  1  |  B  |  1  |
|  1  |  D  |  1  |
|  2  |  B  |  0  |
|  2  |  C  |  0  |
|  2  |  A  |  0  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `bool_or()` for this:

```
select t.*, bool_or(val = 'D') over(partition by id) res
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=572cf79d77d8284b5d28819f264d0571)**:

```
id | val | res
-: | :-- | :--
 1 | A   | t  
 1 | B   | t  
 1 | D   | t  
 2 | B   | f  
 2 | C   | f  
 2 | A   | f
```

This gives you a boolean result. If you want it as an integer value instead, then:

```
(bool_or(val = 'D') over(partition by id))::int
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but in standard ANSI SQL, you can use a `filter()` clause:

```
count(*) filter (where val = 'D') over (partition by id) > 0
```